# Jersey custom constraint mapping

Tags: java, validation, jersey

I want to add bean validation to Jersey programmatically(without annotations or XML). I've found:

1. How to create programmatically constraints maps. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-programmatic-api
2. And how to configure Jersey bean validation. https://jersey.java.net/documentation/2.8/bean-validation.html#d0e11848

Combining it I've got something like this

```
public class ValidationConfigurationContextResolver implements ContextResolver<ValidationConfig> {

  @Context
  private ResourceContext resourceContext;

  @Override
  public ValidationConfig getContext(Class<?> arg0) {
    HibernateValidatorConfiguration configuration = Validation
            .byProvider(HibernateValidator.class)
            .configure();

    ConstraintMapping constraintMapping = configuration.createConstraintMapping();



    constraintMapping
            .type(SomeBean.class)
            .ignoreAllAnnotations()
            .property("name", ElementType.FIELD)
            .constraint(new SizeDef().max(5).min(2));

    configuration.addMapping(constraintMapping);


    ValidationConfig config = new ValidationConfig();
    config.constraintValidatorFactory(configuration.getDefaultConstraintValidatorFactory());
    config.parameterNameProvider(new CustomParameterNameProvider());

    return  config;
  }

  /**
   * See ContactCardTest#testAddInvalidContact.
   */
  private class CustomParameterNameProvider implements ParameterNameProvider {

    private final ParameterNameProvider nameProvider;

    public CustomParameterNameProvider() {
      nameProvider = Validation.byDefaultProvider().configure().getDefaultParameterNameProvider();
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> getParameterNames(final Constructor<?> constructor) {
      return nameProvider.getParameterNames(constructor);
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> getParameterNames(final Method method) {
      // See ContactCardTest#testAddInvalidContact.

      return nameProvider.getParameterNames(method);
    }
  }
}
```

But it doesnt work. When I debugged I noticed that getContext() method was invoked but any invalid data was passed. What I need to do for adding constraintMapping to Jersey. Jersey ValidationConfig even doesn't extends javax.validation.Configuration.

Comment: I am facing the exact same problem. Got this working somehow?